# Combine two .dll for MS Access

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, dll, itext

I have created a project in Visual studio using the Class Library and written in C# and that uses the [itextsharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) library.

The project has two dlls: project.dll and itextsharp.dll

I want to be able to use this project in another user's laptop so they can use it in MS Access VBA.

I have done a test run of this on a simple project. I created a class library and copied the .dll file over to the other user's pc.
Then I registered it using "regasm testFile.dll /tlb:testFile.tlb /codebase".
Then I was able to open MS Access referencing the testFile.tlb file in VBA Access editor.

But now that I have a project with itextsharp in it, I am not sure what to do.
I tried using regasm like above, it did create a .tlb file, it didn't register it's dll.

I also tried using [ilmerge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=17630) on project.dll and itextsharp.dll but this didn't produce a strong name despite both dll's having a strong name and if I understand correctly it needs a strong name to work.

I tried to give the merged dll's a strong name by using [sn.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sn-exe-strong-name-tool) but when I tried to check to see if it did have a strong name using "sn -v mergeFile.dll" it returned with "mergeFile.dll does not represent a strongly named assembly"

Is there any way for to combine these .dll's into oneor is there a way to insert the itextsharp library into the project.dll?

Comment: You linked iTextSharp to Sourceforge, but it is no longer available there. Please link to itextpdf.com or to github.com/itext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to use iTextSharp in VBA without merging the DLL's.

To use C# code in Access VBA you need to be able to add the C# DLL as a reference to Access VBA editor.
When this was being done in DataCam we needed to use a third party library call ed iTextSharp.dll which can make things tricky when you want to use it in VBA

Do the following:

**In Visual Studio**

- When creating a C# project select the Class Library template
- Download and add the iTextSharp DLL to your Project
- Write your C# code
- Go to the Project tab

  - Select the project's Properties
  - Select the Application tab
  - Select Assembly Information
  - Tick "Make assembly COM Visible"
  - Select the Build tab
  - Tick "Register for COM interop"
  - Select the Signing tab
  - Tick "Sign the assembly"
  - Choose a Strong name key file
  - Either use existing Key file or create a new one
- When this is done select "Build" at the top of the screen

  - This will create the DLL, TLB and PDB files that you will need to use in VBA these can be found in the bin, Debug folders of the project

**Register the files**

- Copy the project's  DLL, TLB and PDB files to the computer's SysWOW64 folder
- Also copy iTextSharp's DLL and TLB file from the same folder to SysWOW64
- Open the Command Prompt as Administrator

  - Register the project's DLL file using the command Regasm.exe
  - Example 1:
  - Regasm.exe project.dll /tlb:project.tlb /codebase
  - Example 2:
  - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe C:\Windows\SysWOW64\projectName.dll /tlb:projectName.tlb /codebase

**In Access VBA**

- Got to VBA editor
- Select tools then references
- Select the project's TLB and iTextSharp's DLL files
- You will now be able to use C# code in VBA

**Note 1:**

The C# methods I wrote could be used in VBA but I had to exclude the brackets

Eg.

methodName("Hello, World") - didn't work in VBA

methodName "Hello, World" - worked in VBA

**Note 2:**

If you updated the project and want to add it VBA be sure to unregister the old DLL.

To do so use Regasm.exe project.dll /u